# How to extract specific pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I am new to python
I want to extract specific pattern in python 3.5
pattern: **digit character digit**
characters can be *** + - / x X**

how can I do this?

I have tried to use pattern [0-9\*/+-xX\0-9] but it returns either of the characters present in a string.

example: 2*3 or 2x3 or 2+3 or 2-3 should be matched
but asdXyz should not

Comment: please provide some valid examples.

Comment: I think you can just do `[0-9][\*+-/xX][0-9]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[0-9][*+/xX-][0-9]
```

Or to match a whole string:

```
^[0-9][*+/xX-][0-9]$
```

In Python 3.x, you may discard the `^` (start of string anchor) and `$` (end of string anchor) if you use the pattern in [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) ([demo](https://ideone.com/5CbyIJ)):

```
if re.fullmatch(r'[0-9][*+/xX-][0-9]', '5+5'):
    print('5+5 string found!')
if re.fullmatch(r'[0-9][*+/xX-][0-9]', '5+56'):
    print('5+56 string found!')
# => 5+5 string found!
```

Comment: regex = r"[0-9][*+/xX-][0-9]" this worked. let me do some testing. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ok, I see, I removed the unnecessary answer part. BTW, your pattern just matched a single char from the defined set/ranges. Depending on what method you used, there could be different matching scenarios, but the problem was that you put everything into a single character class.

Answer (score 1):

The [*re.match()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) function will limit the search to the start and end of the string to prevent false positives.

- A digit can be matched with `\d`.
- The operator can be matched with `[x/+\-]` which matches exactly one of `x`, `/`, `+`, or `-` (which is escaped because it is a special regex character).
- The last digit can be matched with `\d`.
- Putting parentheses around each part allows the parts to extracted as separate subgroups.

For example:

```
>>> re.match(r'(\d)([x/+\-])(\d)', '3/4').groups()
('3', '/', '4')
```